# Control content access whilst creating content

Tags: 7, nodes, users

Is there  a way to control access during the content creation process?

With the Content Access module I can setup access controls for individual nodes of the same type, but only after I have created that content.

Could this process be integrated into the content creation process for the sake of intuitiveness.

Answer (score 2):

**Workbench, Workbench Access** and **Workbench Moderation** modules could help you with access control and content management.

**[Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench)** improves content management for Drupal 7. 
It has more then 1200 reported installs.

Workbench allows to :

- simplify the user interface for content creators and editors 
  limiting training and support time.
- control who has access to edit any content based on an organization's
  structure not the website structure
- customize editorial workflow that integrates with the access control 
  feature described above or works independently on its own

**Workbench Access**
Workbench Access provides hierarchical permissions across "Sections" of your website. You can use menus, taxonomy or create your own hierarchical structure for controlling access to the content.

**Workbench Moderation**
provides editorial workflow. It is a flexible system. It provides default workflow states like Drafts, Needs Review, and Published. You can also change these states to suit your needs.